# How do I redefine the projection of a DEM?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, dem

I have a DEM that was exported from AutoCAD civil 3D 2013 but it's in the wrong projection. I'm using an area specific projection that was not provided as an option in CAD DEM export dialog box. I choose an other projection to finish the export and now I want to associate the proper projection to the DEM. Is there a way to redefine the projection of the DEM in ArcGIS 10.1 to the proper one?

Comment: Can you choose a nonprojected coordinate system to export your CAD Data like WGS1984 and then project to your appropriate system once you import into ArcGIS? The tool in Arc to project is Project (Data Management). You will first need to Define(Data Management) using the coordinate system you exported out of AutoCAD if Arc reads your coordinate system as "Undefined"

Comment: Have you looked at [**Define Projection**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000)?  I think this is the tool you need.

Comment: @Conor It appears that AutoCAD only supplies common projected coordinate systems when exporting a TIN to DEM

Comment: @PROBERT maybe I am looking in the wrong spot but I don't see a button to clear the coordinate system

Comment: @PolyGeo I have tried the define projection tool and I don't get any errors but in the layer properties it isn't shown as changed. I have tried going into ArcCatalog and editing the properties there to change the coordinate system and that doesn't seem to stick either.

Comment: Maybe I am not clearly myself what I wrote earlier but you can go to ArcMap.   Right click on the Layers Properties which brings up Data Frame Properties  Go to Coordinate System. There is a button to the right that looks like a Globe with yellow start that has down arrow. Click there, There are three to choose from : New, Import, and Clear.

Comment: @PROBERT Thanks, I found the clear button. I never knew that it existed. Unfortunately it looks like it only clears the coordinate system assigned to the data frame not to the data (dem) itself.